# Why does table refresh when it is part of merge even when the `include is report refresh` is disabled on the source table (source of merge)?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have 2 tables in Power query.

1. Sales
2. Rate

I have merged Rate into Sales and pulled in Rate.percentage column into the Sales table.

Then I unchecked the `include in report refresh` option on Rate table. My intention is that the Rate table should never refresh and Sales table merge to the Rate table should always consider the value as of the time of 1st refresh that I do when performing the 1st data load.

To test this I updated some rate percentage values in the Rate table in the db, and notice that in the report visual the values that come from the Rate table still shows old value (which I expected). However, the Rate.percentage column that is part of the Sales table (due to merge) shows updated values. Is this expected? and how to prevent this?

I also tried unchecking the `enable load` option. With this the Rate table cannot be used inn visual (expected), but the rate.percentage on the Sales table visuals show updated Rates (when I change the values in the db and hit refresh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the way PQ works. It doesn't store any data. If you have a table A that you are refreshing which is merging in values from Table B which you have told not to refresh, then PQ wouldn't be able to proceed. It needs to restream that data from Table B despite your instruction not to refresh so that it can refresh Table A.

That instruction to not refresh Table B only works if the table is used in isolation and not used in other queries.

Comment: So is it good practice then to apply the range start/end parameters to the Table B. So that when Table A refreshes its partitions then for each partition it can query only the relevant portions of the Table B. Otherwise I am noticing that it queries the entire Table B for each partition from Table A.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not 100% sure. You would have to test it and try it to see if it improves what you're seeing.

Comment: Yes I did try this and for each refresh for the Table A's partitions, it applies the same date range filters to the Table B. Rather than fetching entire Table B for each partition of Table A.

Comment: This is probably an edge case for Power Query and so not 100% optimised. You could try raising a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: I think it is the correct behavior because the Table B filters indeed get applied as it is merged with Table A